# filter_all for !is.na() in R still yields missing values

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, filtering, na

I'm trying to use dplyr's filter_all() to yield all rows that do *not* have any missing data. I'm using dplyr's built in starwars dataset. When I use this code to yield that *does* have any missing values, it works seamlessly:

```
 library(dplyr)
 data("starwars")

rows_with_NAs <- starwars %>%
  filter_all(any_vars(is.na(.)))
```

However, if I try to find the rows that do *not* have any missing values with this code:

```
rows_without_NAs <- starwars %>%
  filter_all(any_vars(!is.na(.)))
```

I still get rows with NAs.

```
head(rows_without_NAs)
```

Why is this and how could I fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: You are looking for any variable to have a not-missing value. I think you want to move the negation outside - `!any_vars(is.na(.))`

Comment: @thelatemail, when I try that, I receive the following error message: Error in is_quosure(e2) : argument "e2" is missing, with no default. If you're able to get it to work, can you send me your syntax? Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`tidyr` has the `drop_na()` operator for this.

```
library(tidyverse)

data("starwars")

rows_without_NAs <- starwars %>%
    drop_na()
```

Comment: I didn't know of this function! One small correction for any future people looking for this solution is that drop_na() is in tidyr, not dplyr, but it works all the same. Thanks, @Simon Woodward!

Comment: One of the things about programming these days is that there are so many libraries out there, there's probably something to do what you want, but it's often really hard to find it.